# Android app and API NopCommerce Http запросы

Tags: c#, android-studio, http

Всем доброго времени суток. Задачу себе нарисовал: написать простенькое приложение с http запросами.
Имеется сайт на платформе NopCommerce. С ней я тоже пытаюсь разобраться.
Нашел на Git такой вот Api:
https://github.com/SevenSpikes/api-plugin-for-nopcommerce
Вопрос, как его внедрить в приложение? Скачаю я репозиторий ,а как связать мой сайт с приложением...не могу додумать.
С классами, адаптерами я разбираюсь сейчас, а вот дальше тупик. Тупик связан с отсутствием документации по nopCommerce.

Comment: "написатьприложение с http запросами". Точно нужен левый софт? Задача какая?

Comment: задача. Есть интернет магазин с достаточно большим количеством товаров. Хочу реализовать приложение и как я понял это лучше делать через Http запросы и API платформы на которой сайт.